# Включить (активировать) компас на карте Yandex MapKit Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, yandexmapkit

подскажите, как включить (активировать) стандартный компас от Яндекса, как в приложении Yandex Maps для Android, на карте Yandex MapKit Android 3.0.0? В документации данной информации не нашлось.

Прикрепляю изображение компаса с Yandex Maps для Android

[image: Компас с Yandex Maps для Android]

Answer (score 1):

Продублирую ответ с github:

В MapKit нет готового компаса и его потребуется реализовать самостоятельно. 
Для этого можно использовать [`UserLocationLayer`](https://tech.yandex.ru/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/user_location/package-summary-docpage/).

Comment: Может есть какие-то примеры?

Comment: @AlexS MapKit зарелизился только недавно, пока таких примеров нет